# writing to df.to_csv() major speed issue

Tags: python, pandas

I'm working on a project in pandas with a dataframe that is writing extremely slowly. The shape is, (4116, 131711). Its dtype is float. Its written 81 rows to file in ten minutes. I am not swapping; though the process is using  36Gb of memory (which is also odd). When running on a test on a subset of the data, 20 rows write in about 7 seconds.

I also have now observed that it writes the last 1.5 gb of the output in under two minutes after spending over an hour writing the first gb. 
I'm quite confused.

The data is simply read into a dict, turned into a dataframe, filtered on some summary stats, missing values filled and then written.

Pandas version 0.15.2
python 2.7.9
gcc 4.4.7
numpy 1.9.2

Any ideas?

```
imps = DataFrame(dict,index=pos)

imps.replace(5,np.nan,inplace=True)

imps = imps.ix[imps.var(1) > .05]
MAF = imps.apply(maf,axis = 1)
imps = imps.ix[MAF>.15]
imps = imps.transpose()

imps.fillna(MAF,inplace=True)


outn = Imp_genotypes.rstrip('.txt')+'.dosage.txt'



imps.to_csv(outn, header=False)
```

Comment: Can you post your code, also what version pandas, python and numpy are you using?

Comment: Using trunk pandas, it took me 17 min to write a 10G csv file from a frame of that shape; it took 8 minutes to write the transpose (more rows, fewer columns); and only 30s to write to HD5.  So I'm not seeing the pathology, but I wouldn't use csv for such a big file anyway.

Comment: @DSM side issue: https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/3186 if you are interested!

Comment: @DSM I'm formatting for downstream software which is looking for a csv.

Comment: How much physical memory on this server? You are banging very large data sets (multi-GB bare minimum for the data, even before indexing structures, IO and format buffers, etc.). In CSV you're not just writing out your half-billion floating point values (say 8 bytes each), but a string serialization of them. At ~19 bytes per data point, you're talking ~10 GB data. While not impossible, as @DSM indicates, this is outside CSV's "sweet spot." What kind of memory/disk/IOPS resources does your system have to handle it?

Comment: Server that its running on has a terabyte of physical memory. Input file is 3gb of fixed length ints. And as I said, the goal is an input for another software package.

Comment: I'm messing around with chunksize = to see if that helps.